# django: how to find the context variable in inline Model if we use custom template

Tags: python, django

Below is my code

```
class CommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model= Comments
    extra=0


    template = "admin/comments.html"



class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CommentInline]

admin.site.register(Blog,BlogAdmin)
```

In the comments.html file

```
{% for comments in comments_list %}
    {{ comments.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it is not printing anything, but If use a default template it prints the values

I am just trying to use different template for inline class

Comment: Your first code block is `admin.py`. Unless you're trying to write some kind of custom admin component, `views.py` is what's relevant. Also `models.py`.

Comment: @kungphu yes, the code is for admin side only, I am just trying to change inline part of the template